# zabbix 4.4 frontend 503 error for assests

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, zabbix

I am trying to setup a zabbix server, to which I will eventually connect remote agent hosts. Zabbix's claim to be up and running in 5 minutes seems to be a little misleading, but that is for another day

I installed zabbix 4.4 using the rpm packages on a CentOS 7 server. After configuring the MySql database, the zabbix-server.conf, etc. I open a browser and receive some weird issues.

The first issue, opening http://[host ip address]/zabbix, returns `The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.`

If I then try http://[host ip address]/zabbix/index.php, I see the screen but there is no styling. Using Chrome browser I opened the developer tools and see several 503 errors (service unavailable) in the console.

Researching this, I've found where I may have to change the owner and set permissions so I

```
chown -R apache:apache /usr/share/zabbix
chmod -R =x /usr/share/zabbix
```

That has not helped.

There are no errors in either /var/log/httpd/access_log or error_log. I've enabled php to log errors, `error_log = /var/log/php/php_errors.log` and created the parent directory /var/log/php, but no file has been generated

I'm not sure what else to do.

Setup and Configuration:

- OS: CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 Apache: Server version:
- Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
- PHP: 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 08:36:40)
- /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf:

```
#
# Zabbix monitoring system php web frontend
#

Alias /zabbix /usr/share/zabbix

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value max_execution_time 300
        php_value memory_limit 128M
        php_value post_max_size 16M
        php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
        php_value max_input_time 300
        php_value max_input_vars 10000
        php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
        php_value date.timezone America/New_York
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/conf">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/app">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/include">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/local">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Everything I have read points to a misconfiguration of Apache, but I think I've been through everything I can think of.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the installation manual https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/installation/install_from_packages/rhel_centos step by step very carefully. I'm pretty sure it covers the correct installation steps as I did so myself and ended up with properly working zabbix installation.

To your issue - without posting error logs it's difficult to say what exactly is wrong but I assume it may be some of the following:

1. your installation PHP source download is incomplete
2. your PHP installation is missing critical modules
3. your PHP/apache/MySQL configuration is incomplete or misconfigured

if you need further help you need to verify above points and correctly setup php and apache error logging. Post the logs in your question afterwards.

There's also zabbix server log usually in `/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server/` directory that could have a hint what's wrong.